# Seven levels through Europe

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues, geography

Let's take a little trip through Europe, shall we?

> [image]
>
> Each level forms a word chain. Even-numbered levels (yellow) go clockwise, odd-numbered ones (white) go anticlockwise.
>
> Each level has an answer which points to a certain region of Europe. This answer always covers the two central squares of the left column when the answers are put correctly in the grid.
>
> The seven regions are the BRITISH isles, the IBERIAN peninsula, the BENELUX countries, CENTRAL Europe, the BALKANS, the BALTICS, and EASTERN Europe (not necessarily in this order).
>
> The final answer is a landmark. The grid below can be used to find out the country where it's in. (This may be useful, but the final answer can be solved without it.)
>
> [image]

**Level 1 (↺)**

> a) Make purchases for clergyman without dumb Thai followers (4)
> b) Furry creature makes fifth dinner with Chinese pan (4)
> c) Remarkable chant turns initially left and right (8)
> d) Tolkien dwarf deceased, reportedly raided (9)
> e) Dylan's twin gets up to join train cars (6)
> f) TV doctor does not get to finish letter (3)
> g) Swim team finishers make clergyman (4)
> h) Car hub arbitrarily stores vegetable (7)
> i) Originally marketed Apple computer! (3)
> j) Eva drinks regularly, makes money (5)
> k) Celtic people inspect shades (8)
> l) City numbered 55-4 or 56-5? (4)
> m) Unusually keen body part (4)
> n) Definitely head evil! (5)

**Level 2 (↻)**

> a) Poet cartoon character (5)
> b) Automobile headquarters (4)
> c) Short sibling returns ball (3)
> d) Kangaroo makes concealed space (4)
> e) Subject is hidden in laptop icons (5)
> f) Reduce a short miniature in serving (8)
> g) In an odd way, sulfur rust garbles words (5)
> h) Maker of action flicks or armoured vehicle (6)
> i) Historical region and location for rhapsody (7)
> j) Wearing neck-covering clothing, reportedly painted (8)
> k) Truncated palindrome language is a different language (5)
> l) Japanese artist devastates Tokyo, striking giant tail (4)

**Level 3 (↺)**

> a) One in three parts of rum behind sandwich ($1a$) leads to confusion (8)
> b) Actress ($2l$) takes McCartney's heart in the end of time (6)
> c) Before second hand clenched around last ($2a$) (5)
> d) Laughing at ($2h$)'s spiritual journey (4)
> e) Noted ($2g$) retracted in conclusions (7)
> f) Island with ($2k$) minority language (4)
> g) City with televised emergency ($2d$) (4)
> h) ($1g$) head figure is Arabic leader (4)
> i) Blue ($2c$) with a twisted heart (5)
> j) ($1d$) with an outer covering (7)

**Level 4 (↻)**

> a) Tribe lost on ($3f$) (6)
> b) Vintage winery ($1j$) secretly (4)
> c) Battle site with ($3j$) cypress (5)
> d) Singer's dress about fourth ($2e$) (4)
> e) ($3i$)'s top surveyer has black gold (4)
> f) ($1m$) joint regularly brightly coloured (4)
> g) Country's ($3c$) lady gets an award finally (4)
> h) ($2j$) shirt covering beginners born yesterday (5)
> i) Strangely, no middle-aged ($1e$) starts lynching (5)
> j) Virtual places to take a ($2b$) before finishing dishes (5)

**Level 5 (↺)**

> a) Wake to start fires with ($4f$) in the mountains (7)
> b) Nearly last ($4a$) surrounded by exotic malts (6)
> c) Dutch octet follows the lead of ($4c$) vessel (5)
> d) ($4g$) with large quadricycle, among others (6)
> e) Browse ($4j$) for extraordinary furs (4)
> f) Industry covers up ($4h$) score (3)
> g) Two pens ($4i$) produce digits (4)

**Level 6 (↻)**

> a) ($5b$) renowned little city (4)
> b) Food buried in Shinto ($5a$) (4)
> c) Execution ($3e$) not in place (6)
> d) Province's complicated rules about ($5c$) terminal (6)
> e) Half of ($5d$)'s capital backing short pastor Phoenix (5)

**Level 7 (↺)**

> a) ($6d$) city not fast to give points as capital (8)
> b) Bury ($6a$)'s entrails next to grave (6)

Comment: Wow @jafe. That is a lot of effort. Your puzzles are well thought out. +1. Another note. Is it me or it just seems like the readership on PSE has suddenly come down in February?

Comment: This is fun. @jafe, am I right in thinking that (4h) is a little bit loose? I mean, the definition part of the clue is (adjective) (noun) and the answer is X, and really it's X (noun) that matches (adjective) (noun), right? (Apologies if this is incomprehensible; I'm trying to avoid spoilers.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan If I understand correctly, I think you're right. Wiktionary lists X as a noun with the meaning "X (noun)", but in normal speech I think you'd be more likely to say "X (noun)" than just "X"... Does that make sense?

Comment: Huh, so it does. Never heard it used that way. Also, I think you have all three parts, not just two, in 3a.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Hmm, that's correct... Fixed, thanks!

Comment: While I'm quibbling about everything, looks to me like 4d is also slightly iffy: if taken as transitive, the object of the relevant verb is the _person_ in the clue and the _thing_ in the answer. No?

Comment: Aargh. I have just about everything (including the final answer) but there's one damn clue I am failing to solve :-).

Comment: Bleh, I decided to post it without that one clue. I'm sure I'll kick myself when I figure it out. Or when someone else does.

Comment: A couple more quibbles: 1g (turns? why?), 3e (I can see something anagrammish going on but really don't understand the wordplay).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Fixed 1g. You're right, the "turn" didn't belong there... For 3e I was thinking rot13 (er cyhf vafhygf zvahf va).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Only just figured out the problem with 4d... Yeah, I suppose the two aren't really synonyms now that I think about it.

Comment: Ah! Never got close to thinking of _that_ for 3e :-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, the solutions to the cryptic clues:

> ```
> Level 1 [Iberian peninsula - Vettones]
>
> SHOP      a) Make purchases for clergyman without dumb Thai followers (4)
> EWOK      b) Furry creature makes fifth dinner with Chinese pan (4)
> SINGULAR  c) Remarkable chant turns initially left and right (8)
> BOMBARDED d) Tolkien dwarf deceased, reportedly raided (9)
> COUPLE    e) Dylan's twin gets up to join train cars (6)
> PHI       f) TV doctor does not get to finish letter (3)
> IMAM      g) Swim team finishers turn to clergyman (4)
> RHUBARB   h) Car hub arbitrarily stores vegetable (7)
> MAC       i) Originally marketed Apple computer! (3)
> EARNS     j) Eva drinks regularly, makes money (5)
> VETTONES  k) Celtic people inspect shades (8)
> LVIV      l) City numbered 55-4 or 56-5? (4)
> KNEE      m) Unusually keen body part (4)
> DEVIL     n) Definitely head evil! (5)
>
> Level 2 [Central Europe]
>
> HOMER     a) Poet cartoon character (5)
> SEAT      b) Automobile headquarters (4)
> ORB       c) Short sibling returns ball (3)
> ROOM      d) Kangaroo makes concealed space (4)
> TOPIC     e) Subject is hidden in laptop icons (5)
> DIMINISH  f) Reduce a short miniature in serving (8)
> SLURS     g) In an odd way, sulfur rust garbles words (5)
> ABRAMS    h) Maker of action flicks or armoured vehicle (6)
> BOHEMIA   i) Historical region and location for rhapsody (7)
> COLOURED  j) Wearing neck-covering clothing, reportedly painted (8)
> MALAY     k) Truncated palindrome language is a different language (5)
> YOKO      l) Japanese artist devastates Tokyo, striking giant tail (4)
>
> Level 3 [Eastern Europe?]
>
> DELIRIUM  a) One in two parts of rum behind sandwich (1a:SHOP) leads to confusion (8)
> MONROE    b) Actress (2l:YOKO) takes McCartney's heart in the end of time (6)
> FIRST     c) Before second hand clenched around last (2a:HOMER) (5)
> HAJJ      d) Laughing at (2h:ABRAMS)'s spiritual journey (4)
> RESULTS   e) Noted (2g:SLURS) retracted in conclusions (7)
> JAVA      f) Island with (2k:MALAY) minority language (4)
> TVER      g) City with televised emergency (2d:ROOM) (4)
> ALIF      h) (1g:IMAM) head figure is Arabic leader (4)
> EARTH     i) Blue (2c:ORB) with a twisted heart (5)
> SHELLED   j) (1d:BOMBARDED) with an outer covering (7)
>
> Level 4 [Benelux - Ypres]
>
> NAVAJO    a) Tribe lost on (3f:JAVA) (6)
> YEAR      b) Vintage winery (1j:EARNS) secretly (4)
> YPRES     c) Battle site with (3j:SHELLED) cypress (5)
> DION      d) Singer's dress about fouth (2e:TOPIC) (4)
> SOIL      e) (3i:EARTH)'s top surveyer has black gold (4)
> NEON      f) (1m:KNEE) joint regularly brightly coloured (4)
> LAND      g) Country's (3c:FIRST) lady gets an award finally (4)
> RUGBY     h) (2j:COLOURED) shirt covering beginners born yesterday (5)
> ODDLY     i) Strangely, no middle-aged (1e) starts lynching (5)
> SITES     j) Virtual places to take a (2b:SEAT) before finishing dishes (5)
>
> Level 5 [Baltic states]
>
> FUNERAL   a) Wake to start fires with (4f:NEON) in the mountains (7)
> ALMOST    b) Nearly last (4a:NAVAJO) surrounded by exotic malts (6)
> YACHT     c) Dutch octet follows the lead of (4c:YPRES) vessel (5)
> LATVIA    d) (4g:LAND) with large quadricycle, among others (6)
> SURF      e) Browse (4j:SITES) for extraordinary furs (4)
> TRY       f) Industry covers up (4h:RUGBY) score (3)
> TOES      g) Two pens (4i:ODDLY) produce digits (4)
>
> Level 6 [British Isles]
>
> RENO      a) (5b:ALMOST) renowned little city (4)
> TOFU      b) Food buried in Shinto (5a:FUNERAL) (4)
> OUTPUT    c) Execution (3e:RESULTS) not in place (6)
> ULSTER    d) Province's complicated rules about (5c:YACHT) terminal (6)
> RIVER     e) Half of (5d:LATVIA)'s capital backing short pastor Phoenix (5)
>
> Level 7 [Balkan states]
>
> BELGRADE  a) (6d:ULSTER) city not fast to give points as capital (8)
> ENTOMB    b) Bury (6a:RENO)'s entrails next to grave (6)
> ```

Now we can fill in the grid:

> [image: completed grid]

and observe

> across the middle THE PARENT TERRITORY TELEPHONES which (as one of only two possibilities, really) we can reword as THE MOTHERLAND CALLS, the name of a large sculpture in Volgograd in Russia.

So we didn't need that extra hint, but

> to use it we fill in those 7-letter region names (I'd *thought* the way they were described seemed a little strained) in order of use (layer 1 first etc.):
>  I B E **R** I A N
>  C E N T R A L
>  E A **S** T E R N
>  B E N E L **U** X
>  B A L T I C **S**
>  B R **I** T I S H
>  B A L K **A** N S
>  and read off letters according to the numbers given to get RUSSIA.

Thanks to @Tom for providing, in comments, the key observation for one clue I'd been unable to get. (I don't know whether Tom solved the clue as well; I expect so.) And then for pointing out (politely) the idiocy of the answer I proposed and showing me a better one :-).

Comment: 1 e) may be rot13(Qlyna naq Pbyr).

Comment: @Tom Never heard of them before. But I guess that must be right. Editing. [Done. Thanks!]

Comment: Tiny change, thinking of rot13(pbhcyr - gb wbva genva pnef).

Comment: rot13(V'ir tbg 1r! )

Comment: @Tom Duh! Of course that's better than what I had. [I've now re-edited my answer accordingly. Thanks again.]

Comment: Another homonym was intended for 2j (the wordplay being the last two words), but interestingly this works just as well. Nice work!

Comment: Huh. I thought I'd checked that it had to be that way around because the other way had the wrong number of letters. Apparently I can't count to 8. As you say, it works either way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to each cryptic clues and reasons:

***CAUTION:** This post may contain URLs, spoilers and encoded words.*

---

Level 1:

Make purchases for clergyman without dumb Thai followers (4)

> **SHOP** (not sure yet; purchases)

Furry creature makes fifth dinn**e**r with Chinese pan (4)

> **EWOK** (def: Furry creature; dinn**E**r + **WOK** a Chinese pan)

Remarkable chant turns initially left and right (8)

> **SINGULAR** (def: Remarkable; **SING** + **U**-<s>turns</s> + **L**eft **A**nd **R**ight)

Tolkien dwarf deceased, reportedly raided (9)

> **BOMBARDED** (not sure yet)

Dylan's twin gets up to join train cars (6)

> **COUPLE** (def: twin; not sure yet)

TV doctor does not get to finish letter (3)

> **PHI** (def: Greek letter; not sure yet)

Swim team finishers turn to clergyman (4)

> **IMAM** (def: clergyman; Sw**IM** te**AM**)

Car hub arbitrarily stores vegetable (7)

> **RHUBARB** (def: vegetable; Ca**R HUB ARB** itrarily)

Originally marketed Apple computer! (3)

> **MAC** (def: Apple product; **M**arketed **A**pple **C**omputer)

Eva drinks regularly, makes money (5)

> **EARNS** (def: makes money; Even letters: **E**v**A** d**R**i**N**k**S**)

Celtic people inspect shades (8)

> **VETTONES** (not sure yet)

City numbered 55-4 or 56-5? (4)

> **LVIV** (def: City * not sure yet * ; LVI V or LV IV)

Unusually keen body part (4)

> **KNEE** (def: body part; KEEN scrambled)

Definitely head evil! (5)

> **DEVIL** (def: something evil; hea**D** **EVIL**! )

---

Level 2:

Poet cartoon character (5)

> **HOMER** (def: Poet; not sure yet about "cartoon")

Automobile headquarters (4)

> **SEAT** (ddef)

Short sibling returns ball (3)　　　　　[ *This clue has a problem.* ]

> **ORB** (def: ball; **BRO**<s>ther</s> scrambled)

Kangaroo makes concealed space (4)

> **ROOM** (def: space; Kanga**ROO M**akes)

Subject is hidden in laptop icons (5)

> **TOPIC** (def: Subject; lap**TOP** **IC**ons)

Reduce a short miniature in serving (8)

> **DIMINISH** (def: Reduce; **MINI**<s>ature</s> in **DISH**)

In an odd way, sulfur rust garbles words (5)

> **SLURS** (def: garbles words * not sure yet * ; **S**u**L**f**U**r **R**u**S**t)

Maker of action flicks or armoured vehicle (6)

> **ABRAMS** (def: the name of a company; not sure yet)

Historical region and location for rhapsody (7)

> **BOHEMIA** (ddef)

Wearing neck-covering clothing, reportedly painted (8)　　　　　[ *This clue has a problem.* ]

> **COLOURED** (def: painted; homophone of COLLARED)

Truncated palindrome language is a different language (5)

> **MALAY** (def: language; not sure yet)

Japanese artist devastates Tokyo, striking gian**t** tail (4)

> **YOKO** (def: Japanese name; Scrambled <s>t</s>**OKYO**)

---

Level 3:
***NOTE:** If you see an encoded word, it's actually one of the **BOLD***
*words from the previous pages.*

One in two parts of rum behind sandwich *rot13:FUBC*  leads to confusion (8)

> **DELIRIUM** (def: confusion; **I** in **RUM** after **DELI**)

Actress *rot13:LBXB* takes McCartney's heart in the end of time (6)

> **MONROE**

Before second hand clenched around last *rot13:UBZR**E*** (5)

> **FIRST** (def: Before second; **FIST** + <s>Home</s>**R**)

Laughing at *rot13:NOENZF'f* spiritual journey (4)

> **HAJJ** (def: journey * not sure yet *; **HA** + ? not sure yet)

Noted *rot13:FYHEF* retracted in conclusions (7)

> **RESULTS** (def: conclusions; **SLURS** + ET? scrambled)

Island with *rot13:ZNYNL* minority language (4)

> **JAVA** (programming language)

City with televised emergency *rot13:EBBZ* (4)

> **TVER** (def: City; **TV**+ E.R.)

*rot13:VZNZ* head figure is Arabic leader (4)

> **ALIF** (not sure yet)

Blue *rot13:BEO* with a twisted heart (5)

> **EARTH** (def: Blue *rot13:BEO*; **HEART** scrambled)

*rot13:OBZONEQRQ* with an outer covering (7)

> **SHELLED** (ddef;)

---

Level 4:

Tribe lost on *rot13:WNIN* (6)

> **NAVAJO** (def: tribe; **ON JAVA** scrambled)

Vintage winery *rot13:RNEAF* secretly (4)

> **YEAR** (def: time; winer**Y *RNE***af )

Battle site with *rot13:FURYYRQ* cypress (5)

> **YPRES** (def: site; c**YPRES*s)

Singer's dress about fouth *rot13:GBCVP* (4)　　　　　[ *Spelling error detected* ] [ *Fixed later* ]
**EDITED**: Singer's dress about fourth *rot13:GBCVP* (4)

> **DION** (def: [Singer](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=Celine%20Dion&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=celine%20dion&sc=10-11&sk=&cvid=3B16B5764C2A4B9EB9EADEAD114AB463); **DON** *v.* + top**I**c)

*rot13:RNEGU'f* top surveyer has black gold (4)

> **SOIL** (def: *rot13:RNEGU*; **S**urveyer + **OIL**)

*rot13:XARR* joint regularly brightly coloured (4)

> **NEON** (def: brightly coloured; *x**A**r**R*** j**O**i**N**t)

Country's *rot13:SVEFG* lady gets an award finally (4)

> **LAND** (def: Country; **L**ady + **AN** awar**D** )

*rot13:PBYBHERQ* shirt covering beginners born yesterday (5)

> **RUGBY** (def: Football; **RUG** + **B**orn **Y**esterday)

Strangely, no middle-aged *rot13:PBHCYR* starts lynching (5)

> **ODDLY** (def: Strangely,; **0** **DD** + **LY** nching )

Virtual places to take a *rot13:FRNG* before finishing dishes (5)

> **SITES** (def: places; **SIT** *frng* + dish**ES** )

---

Level 5:

Wake to start fires with *rot12:ZQAZ* in the mountains (7)

> **FUNERAL** (not sure yet)

Nearly last *rot12:ZMHMVA* surrounded by exotic malts (6)

> **ALMOST** (def: Nearly; *zmhmv**A*** around scrambled **MALTS**)

Dutch octet follows the lead of *rot12:KBDQE* vessel (5)

> **YACHT** (not sure yet)

*rot12:XMZP* with large quadricycle, among others (6)

> **LATVIA** (not sure yet)

Browse *rot12:EUFQE* for extraordinary furs (4)

> **SURF** (def: Browse *eufqe*; **FURS** scrambled)

Industry covers up *rot12:DGSNK* score (3)

> **TRY** (def: score; Indus**TRY**)

Two pens *rot12:APPXK* produce digits (4)

> **TOES** (def: digits; **T**w**O** p**E**n**S**)

---

Level 6:

*rot14:OZACGH* renowned little city (4)

> **RENO** (def: city; **RENO**wned)

Food buried in Shinto *rot14:TIBSFOZ* (4)

> **TOFU** (def: Food; Shin**TO *TI***bsfoz)

Execution *rot14:FSGIZHG* not in place (6)

> **OUTPUT** (def: Execution *fsgizhg*; ddef: not in place)

Province's complicated rules about *rot14:MOQVH* terminal (6)

> **ULSTER** (not sure yet)

Half of *rot14:ZOHJWO'g* capital backing short pastor Phoenix (5)

> **RIVER** (def: Phoenix river; **RI**ga + **REV** backwards)

---

Level 7:

(not sure yet)

---

Hidden clue:

*rot13:Gur Cnerag Greevgbel Gryrcubarf?* (3,10,5)

> **THE MOTHERLAND CALLS**

Comment: I found a spelling mistake in clue 4d.